# i am not able to get the selected item of a dropdown on my next page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my app.js

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', ['ngRoute']);
countryApp.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
  $http({
    url: 'countries.json',
    method: "GET",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).success(function (data) {
    $scope.details = data;
    console.log("data---------->", $scope.details);
  }).error(function (data) {
    console.log("data error---------->", $scope.details);
  })
}]);

countryApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  //$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpErrorInterceptor');
  $routeProvider.when('/countrydetails', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/country-detail.html',
    //controller: 'testController',
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/countrylist',
    templateUrl: 'partials/country-list.html',
    controller: 'testController',
    });
}])

countryApp.factory('testService', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  return { }
}])
```

This is my countries-list.html

```
<h1>COUNTRIES</h1>
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="country in details | orderBy:'name'">
    <a>{{country.name}}</a>
  </option>
</select>
<a href="#/countrydetails"><button >click</button></a>
```

I need to get the country name on the next page while button click.
For that i have an html page named country-details.html
What can i do get the name of the country in this html page.

Comment: my country-details.html page looks like  
<h1>{{country.name}}</h1>

Comment: First thing you can not inject `$scope` inside a factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a plunker simulating your scenario. Please check if this helps.
http://plnkr.co/edit/hV16OB?p=preview

This part is important to note.
`$routeProvider.when('/countrydetails/:countryName',`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/i9yaeyV9UoVQuseHoh9Q?p=info    can u please check this.i need the countries in a select boxand then take the name and code to the next page

Comment: i dont need coutries in a list

Answer (score 1):

Set your route like it

```
$routeProvider.when('/countrydetails/:name', {
templateUrl: 'partials/country-detail.html',
});
```

change your **html** like.

```
 <a ng-href="#/countrydetails/{{country.name}}">
<button >click</button></a>
```

It's better to implement to hit a controller function to use proper route but its is what you actually need.

Comment: am not getting directed to the next page while doing this

Comment: still no change......when i click on some country and then click button i get the previous country which was already seen there

Comment: Is there anything else i can do

Comment: Make a plunker of it, so i can fix over there

Answer (score 0):

You can make the href like this:
`<a href="#/countrydetails/{{contry.name}}">`

Set the route as 
`$routeProvider.when('/countrydetails/:name', {`

Then in the Controller of the next page, inject `$routeParams`

```
controller('countryDetailsController', function ($scope, $routeParams) { 
   $scope.countryName = $routeParams.name
});
```

Then, in your html simply use `{{countryName}}`